# grunt-karma cannot find templateCache templates using grunt-angular-templates in generator-cg-angular scaffolded project Gruntfile

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, templates, gruntjs, karma-runner

I used [(Yeoman) generator-cg-angular](https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular) to scaffold my AngularJS web-app, and I'm trying to run unit tests **without using the html2js preprocessor**, but alas it looks like I'm missing something.

#### I changed the folders tree

As per customer request, I moved `index.html`, `app.js` and `app.less` within a folder named `app`, so now the folder structure is something like the following:

```
|--- Gruntfile.js //the Gruntfile.js is in the root folder, just like this generator does out-of-the-box
|___dist
|___unit-test-results
|___node_modules
|___bower_components
|___app
     |____app.js
     |____app.less
     |____index.html
     |____directives
            |____test-directive
                   |____test-directive.js
                   |____test-directive.less
                   |____test-directive.html
                   |____test-directive-spec.js
```

#### My karma task

```
karma: {
      options: {
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [  //this files data is also updated in the watch handler, if updated change there too
          '<%= dom_munger.data.appjs %>',
          'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
          '<%= ngtemplates.main.dest %>',
          'directive/**/*.html',
          createFolderGlobs('*-spec.js')
        ],
        logLevel:'ERROR',
        reporters:['mocha','html'],
        autoWatch: false, //watching is handled by grunt-contrib-watch
        singleRun: true,
        htmlReporter: {
          outputFile: 'unit-test-results/unit-tests'+ grunt.template.today('yyyymmdd') +'.html',

          // Optional
          pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
          groupSuites: true,
          useCompactStyle: true
        }
      },
      all_tests: {
        browsers: ['Chrome','Firefox']
      },
      during_watch: {
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
      },
    },
```

#### The `test-directive-spec.js`

```
describe('testDirective', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('directive/test-directive/test-directive.html')); //manually written

  var scope,compile;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
  }));

  it('should ...', function() {

    var element = compile('<test-directive></test-directive>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(element.text()).toBe('hello world');

  });
});
```

#### `grunt test` fails

When I run `grunt test` configured like this

`grunt.registerTask('test',['dom_munger:read','karma:all_tests']);`

the html report file says he the tests failed because the templates were not found

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module directive/test-directive/test-directive.html due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'directive/test-directive/test-directive.html' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

So I tried adding the `ngtemplates` task to grunt test like this

`grunt.registerTask('test',['dom_munger:read','ngtemplates','karma:all_tests']);`

configuring `ngtemplates` like this

```
ngtemplates: {
      main: {
        options: {
            module: pkg.name,
            htmlmin:'<%= htmlmin.main.options %>',
            url: function(url){ return url.replace('app/','')}
        },
        src: [createFolderGlobs('*.html'),'!'+ indexHtmlPath +'index.html','!_SpecRunner.html'],
        dest: 'temp/templates.js'
      }
    }
```

and produces the following templates.js in a temp folder

```
angular.module('myApp').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  'use strict';

  $templateCache.put('directive/test-directive/test-directive.html',
    "<div>hello world</div>"
  );

}]);
```

But the html reporter still says that the templates are not found.
What am I doing so wrong?
Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.16.1",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.6.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5",
    "grunt-browser-output": "0.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.6",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.9",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.8",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6",
    "grunt-dom-munger": "~3.4",
    "grunt-file-exists": "^0.1.4",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-replace": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-timer": "^0.6.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.6",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of keyboard facerolling, I've come to this solution:

- remove that `directive/**/*.html` from `karma.options.files` task configuration, since **a)** it's not enforcing project ["folders-by-feature"](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y152) structure and **b)** instead getting the templates from `'<%= ngtemplates.main.dest %>'` it's solid enough, you just need to change the `grunt test` task into `grunt.registerTask('test',['dom_munger:read','ngtemplates','karma:all_tests']);`
- remove `beforeEach(module('directive/test-directive/test-directive.html'));` from `test-directive-spec.js`, since it looks like it clashes with the previously described `ngtemplates` mechanism, making the template unavaiable;